# Child Element not responding to Absolute Positioning

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I am trying to place text blocks over images on a portfolio page and have looked up several solutions for solving absolute positioning problems on this site to no avail.

I believe I have a fair understanding of how position: absolute works but my problem is that my text is not treating each image as its parent so the parameters are not having the desired effect (i.e place the text within a specific location inside the image).

Perhaps I have placed my containers incorrectly? I am at a loss.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="container-2">
    <section>
      <!--Page Title-->
      <h1 class="title-2">Portfolio</h1>  
    </section>


    <!--Project Image Links-->

    <!--Project 1-->  
    <div class="img-1">
      <img src="assets/images/colors.jpg"/>
      <div class="hangman">
        <a href="#"><h4>Hangman</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 2-->
    <div class="img-2">
      <img src="assets/images/dj.jpg"/>
      <div class="rpg">
        <a href="#"><h4>RPG Game</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 3-->
    <div class="img-3">
      <img src="assets/images/sunset.jpg"/>
      <div class="trivia">
        <a href="#"><h4>Trivia Game</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 4-->
    <div class="img-4">
      <img src="assets/images/nature.jpg"/>
      <div class="rutgers">
        <a href="#"><h4>Rutgers Info Widget</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 5-->
    <div class="img-5">
      <img src="assets/images/purple.jpg">
      <div class="rps">
          <a href="#"><h4>Rock Paper Scissors</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

And CSS:

```
 .img-1 {
    position: relative;
}
.img-1 h4 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what the textblock I have modified is doing:
[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiPIy.jpg)

Edit:

Well I have tried both of your suggestions and the text (whether as < h4> < p> or < span> all end up not corresponding to the img as its parent.

I apologize in advance but perhaps there is something I am missing within the rest of my CSS that is affecting the positioning the other elements.

Here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url("../images/gravel.png");
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
}
/*Span of About Me page*/
.container {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
/*Span of Portfolio page*/
.container-2 {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
/*Span on Contact Me page*/
.container-3 {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
/*Sticky Footer at bottom of every page*/
.footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 8px solid;
    border-color: #4aaaa5;
    background-color: #666666;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
/*About Me Title*/
.title-1 {
    color: #4aaaa5;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
/*Portfolio Title*/
.title-2 {
    color: #4aaaa5;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
/*Contact Title*/
.title-3 {
    color: #4aaaa5;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
/*Bio Text on index.html*/
.bio {
    color: #777777;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
/* Header at the top of every page*/
.header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    padding-left: 300px;
}
/*My name at the top of each page*/
.Name {
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}
/*Navigation buttons at the top of the page*/
.buttons {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-right: 275px;
    color: #777777;
}
/*Right now just profile picture*/
img {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
/*Decoration for Navigation buttons*/
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777777;
}
/*Input boxes on contact.html*/
.inputs {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #777777;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/*Name input box on contact page*/
.input-1 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 750px;
}
/*Email input box on contact page*/
.input-2 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 750px;
}
/*Message input box on contact page*/
.input-3 {
    width: 750px;
    height: 200px;
}
/*Submit button of contact me page*/
.submit {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*Project image links*/
.content-box img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
.content-box {
    position: relative;
}
.content-box h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    color: #ffffff;

}
```

and HTML for this page as there are several:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <title>Robert-Hardin-Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>


<body>
    <header class="header">
        <!--My name!-->
      <h1 class="Name">Robert Hardin</h1>
      <!--Navigation Tabs-->

      <nav class="buttons">
        <!-- Button that leads to bio-->
        <a href="index.html">About</a>
        &#124
        <!--Button that leads to Portfolio-->
        <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        &#124
        <!--Button that leads to contact information-->
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <br>

  <div class="container-2">
    <section>
      <!--Page Title-->
      <h1 class="title-2">Portfolio</h1>  
    </section>


  <!--Project Image Links-->

    <!--Project 1-->  
    <div class="content-box img-1">
      <img src="assets/images/colors.jpg"/>
      <div class="content hangman">
        <a href="#"><h4>Hangman</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 2-->
    <div class="content-box img-2">
      <img src="assets/images/dj.jpg"/>
      <div class="content rpg">
        <a href="#"><h4>RPG Game</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 3-->
    <div class="content-box img-3">
      <img src="assets/images/sunset.jpg"/>
      <div class="content trivia">
        <a href="#"><h4>Trivia Game</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 4-->
    <div class="content-box img-4">
      <img src="assets/images/nature.jpg"/>
      <div class="content rutgers">
        <a href="#"><h4>Rutgers Info Widget</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 5-->
    <div class="content-box img-5">
      <img src="assets/images/purple.jpg">
      <div class="content rps">
          <a href="#"><h4>Rock Paper Scissors</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>

 </div>

 <br><br>

 <footer class="footer">Copyright © 2019 Robert Hardin</footer>
```

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your absolute positioning is working just fine. I think your problem exists because you are using h4 tags which come with margins on the top and bottom. Either don't use h4 tags and use something like span, or reset the margins on your h4 tags:

```css
.img-1 {
  position: relative;
}

.img-1 span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-2">
  <section>
    <!--Page Title-->
    <h1 class="title-2">Portfolio</h1>
  </section>


  <!--Project Image Links-->

  <!--Project 1-->
  <div class="img-1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    <div class="hangman">
      <a href="#"><span>Hangman</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe this answer was the most helpful, as I had to float: left everything within the content page separately to make it work. The margins most definitely made working within the 960px limit very finicky.

Answer (score 0):

You have four div element inside a container and within that you have images and the h4 tags. You will first need to position the parent element to relative that is all your boxes inside the container should be relative. Please see the solution below

https://codepen.io/salinaacharya/pen/PVoYrV 
html
`

```
<div class="container-2">
    <section>
      <!--Page Title-->
      <h1 class="title-2">Portfolio</h1>  
    </section>


    <!--Project Image Links-->

    <!--Project 1-->  
    <div class="content-box img-1">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTiA15Ti_v2m1EcYm_xsMD2oVJ9b5cJGICrW1GSIkf5DM6v7T3P" />
      <div class="content hangman">
        <a href="#"><h4>Hangman</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 2-->
    <div class="content-box img-2">
      <img src="https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2Fblog%2Flearn-how-to-develop-high-end-mobile-games-in-ue4-with-the-action-rpg-game-sample-project%2FFB_ActionRPGSampleProject-1200x675-555c51d61fc8276009080bab27f74deacf5fabda.jpg"/>
      <div class="content rpg">
        <a href="#"><h4>RPG Game</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 3-->
    <div class="content-box img-3">
      <img src="http://www.bridgeclimb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/160215-ALBERT-YIN-208180549.jpg"/>
      <div class="content trivia">
        <a href="#"><h4>Trivia Game</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 4-->
    <div class="content-box img-4">
      <img src="http://www.newark.rutgers.edu/sites/default/files/rutgersskyline_1.jpg"/>
      <div class="content rutgers">
        <a href="#"><h4>Rutgers Info Widget</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Project 5-->
    <div class="content-box img-5">
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/purple-abstract-background-picture-id504039848?k=6&m=504039848&s=612x612&w=0&h=i-EyrYnpw0U-Zfp4gjLU4QSrvMp-Ildnjchcgt1wpHQ=">
      <div class="content rps">
          <a href="#"><h4>Rock Paper Scissors</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

`

```
    img {
      width:300px;
      height:auto;
    }
    .content-box{
      position: relative;
    }

    .content-box h4 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #4aaaa5;
        color: #ffffff;
        left:15px;
    }
```